# Most efficient palindrome program for python

Tags: python, palindrome

very new to programming and I am trying to solve a few Project Euler problems. I would like to know for a python code which identifies palindrome and non-palindrome. What is the most efficient way to do this? could you please show the code you find most efficient for this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you think would be the most efficient way to do it?

Comment: Having done many many project euler questions with a `def isPali(x): return x==int(str(x)[::-1])`, I can tell you that it's not your palindrome check where you'll be wasting time. There's usually somewhere else to pull time from :P

Comment: When you are writing your question, a list called "***Questions that may already have your answer***" appears. **Use** it. You can even use a fancy feature in your browser called "tabs" to open more than one page at once so you don't lose your place.

Comment: No need to be a jerk about it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this very simply by just checking if the string that you input is equal to itself reversed (that's what a palindrome is).

```
def check_palindrome(s):
    return s == s[::-1]
```

`[::-1]` reverses the string because the `-1` tells how many steps to go by and negative will go through the string in reverse.

If you will need to check if integers are palindromes, you can do:

```
def check_palindrome(s):
    return str(s) == str(s)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of simplicity over (potentially false) optimizations. Start with something straight forward, and move on from there:

```
def is_palindrom(s):
    length = len(s) 
    for i in range(length / 2):
        if s[i] != s[length - i - 1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil -- DonaldKnuth.

Comment: Just a note that this will not work for odd lengthed palindromes

Comment: @Mureinik That and you need to make the `range` a integer, `range(math.floor(length / 2))`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Without any version specification, I just assumed OP meant Python 2. In Python 3 you would be correct, of course.

Comment: lordy how many versions of python are they? and are they relatively the same?

Comment: @user3667054 Many, but the two people care about are 2.7 and 3.4 and those two are not compatible with each other. Personally, I like `range(length//2)` no matter which version I'm using, because it'll work the same for both. But they're not too different.

Comment: "The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet." — Michael A. Jackson